# Unrecognized Selector sent to instance even if method really exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am experiencing this very strange problem and I really don't know why this happens.

I am using a third party MQTT Client lib called [MQTTKit](https://github.com/Noskthing/MQTTKit). I am using it to build an MQTT client that connects to my broker using SSL/TLS. The author said in his blog that if I am going to use the lib together with the methods for TLS support, I'll have to add WITH_TLS=1 this macro to the build settings.

[image]

So I did what he said.

[image]

But when I compile and run the program, I got a crash stating that the method for TLS support was unrecognized. But how come there were no compiler problems when I built the app? Then it just got crash and say that the selector was not found? I don't understand this.

[image]

Comment: From `MQTTKit` page: TLS/SSL support

Mosquitto support TLS/SSL by OpenSSL but it's removed in iOS. So you need compile OpenSSL for iOS Devices (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch, AppleTV) by yurself.

Comment: I would suggest use some other library, that support TLS/SSL by CommonCrypto instead of OpenSSL.

Comment: @Cy-4AH yes, I know that. And I added OpenSSL to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after setting `WITH_TLS=1` macro on the libMQTT target and rebuilt libMQTT.a

Answer (score 2):

From the message in the console, it seems you have MQTTKit twice in your app, once as a linked framework and another time as part of the app itself, and one of them is compiled without TLS support.

You can either remove it from the app target, and just use the framework, and add the macro to the build settings for the framework, or do the opposite.

Comment: Hi, I see you got some point here, but I don't understand how this happened. I have 4 targets in my project. But only one has the Target Membership checked for libMQTT.a (MQTTKit is not a framework). So I don't understand why I have MQTTKit twice in my app...

Comment: Hi, I have just resolved this issue you stated, but it still does not solve my main problem here. Unrecognized selector still occurs.

Comment: @finalstatic - did you set the `WITH_TLS=1` macro on the `libMQTT` target, and then re-build `libMQTT.a`?

Comment: @DonMag Nope, I set WITH_TLS=1 in my app project, not the lib project. Hmmm, maybe that should be the correct way. Maybe I misunderstood some concepts here. I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: @DonMag Hi, thanks for the reminding me. I have solved the problem. Just like you said. I did not set WITH_TLS=1 when building for libMQTT.a. Please make it an answer and I will accept it. Thanks you!